# Error when opening home page in business central when using PLANNER_AND_RULES profile

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I'm trying out RedHat's Business Central using a docker-compose file as described in https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/business-central. At startup it runs a `kie-server` (quay.io/kiegroup/kie-server-showcase:7.67.0.Final) and a `business-central` webserver (quay.io/kiegroup/business-central-workbench-showcase:7.67.0.Final).

Because I'm only interested in the drools part and not the jbpm part, I starting the business-central server with `-Dorg.kie.workbench.profile=PLANNER_AND_RULES` as described in https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.67.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_selecting_a_profile

After login with admin I receive the following error:

```
business-central_1  | 18:11:13,321 ERROR [org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.logger.GenericErrorLoggerServiceImpl] (default task-2) Error from user: admin Error ID: -1427996616 Location: HomePerspective|org.kie.workbench.common.screens.home.client.HomePresenter Exception: Uncaught exception: Client-side exception occurred although RPC call succeeded. Caused by: The profile is not expected and profile to define product name
```

Below, you can find the docker-compose file used:

```yaml
version: "3.2"

services:
  business-central:
    image: quay.io/kiegroup/business-central-workbench-showcase:7.67.0.Final
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
      - "8091:8001"
    environment:
      KIE_SERVER_LOCATION: http://kie-server:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dorg.kie.workbench.profile=PLANNER_AND_RULES"

  kie-server:
    image: quay.io/kiegroup/kie-server-showcase:7.67.0.Final
    environment:
      KIE_SERVER_ID: sample-server
      KIE_SERVER_LOCATION: http://kie-server:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
      KIE_SERVER_CONTROLLER: http://business-central:8080/business-central/rest/controller
      KIE_MAVEN_REPO: http://business-central:8080/business-central/maven2
    ports:
      - "8092:8080"
    depends_on:
      - business-central
volumes:
  business-central_data:
```

UPDATE: on 2022-04-07

I also looked at the source code in github but couldn't find any reference to `PLANNER_AND_RULES`. I looked at several repo's in https://github.com/kiegroup/:

- https://github.com/kiegroup/drools
- https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap
- https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge
- https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-soup

I have no idea how where to look for ;-(.

I found a very disturbing picture on [image] explaining all the repo's that are being used, but it would be good if someone pointed out what repo to look for :-).

Comment: `The profile is not expected and profile to define product name` ... that's some A+ nonsensical messaging there :-/